# Using System.Net.WebProxy with WUApiLib IUpdateSession.WebProxy?

Tags: c#, windows

I'm having a hard time trying to use my proxy settings with the `WUApiLib.WebProxy` / `IUpdateSession.WebProxy`.

I tried the following but no luck:

```
IUpdateSession session = new UpdateSession();

session.WebProxy.AutoDetect(); //Error: Method, Delegate or Event is expected.
```

I then tried the following:

```
 private delegate IUpdateSession D();

 IUpdateSession session = new UpdateSession();
 D proxy = new D(session.WebProxy.AutoDetect()); //Same error...
```

Finally tried simply adding the address:

```
  IUpdateSession session = new UpdateSession();
  session.WebProxy.Address = "http://198.13.44.1:8080"; //This  seems to run, but i'm not sure how i can tell for certain if its working good.
```

Is it possible to pass an instance of `System.Net.WebProxy` to the `WebProxy` found in `IUpdateSession` of `WUApiLib`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IUpdateSession uses the IWebProxy interface for the WebProxy property.

The [AutoDetect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa386922(v=vs.85).aspx) property is a boolean property, so you should be setting it to true or false, not calling it like a method.

Comment: Thanks for that, It's been a long time since I touched that codebase but that is still good to know.